# What is the generalized sum of the following series? $\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \sqrt{s^2 x^2-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, regularization

I tried Mathematica, various regularization methods, including Borel, with no result.

On Math.SE the question was attacked with claims that divergent series cannot have a sum, so I decided to ask at a site of higher level.

Comment: For what range of $s$? For $s=0$, the sum is $\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } i$.

Comment: The now closed cross-post has one answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630266/what-is-the-generalized-sum-of-the-following-series-sum-x-1-infty-sqr

Comment: Anixx, could you clarify the context of your question?  Does this sum arise in some physics context?  Why would one expect a meaningful answer?

Comment: Noting the symbolic series $f(s):=\sum_{x\geq1}\sqrt{s^2x^2-1}$ and the meromorphic function $g(s):=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2x^2-1}}$, I'd use the (formal) functional relation $sf'(s)-f(s)=g(s)$ to obtain a regularization: $f(s)=s(c+\int_{u=\infty}^s  \frac{g(u)}{u}du$) for some constant. Inverting integration and summation in $g$ yields a family of integrals which I fear is not solvable by elementary functions (I'd say elliptic integrals or similar). Don't know if there are computable recombination. Note that the regularization $f$ may well be multivalued...

Comment: ... Hence the choice of the constant $c$ is not unique (and not real in general). A canonical choice would be $c:=\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ due to the asymptotics $s\to+\infty$.

Comment: @Mikhail Katz Actualy, my final aim is to find the generalized vialue of the divergent integral $\int_1^\infty \sqrt{x^2−1}dx$ (area of the hyperbola). For that I need to find limit $\lim_{s→0}s∑$ where ∑ is the generalized value of this sum.

Comment: Why isn't the answer at MSE satisfactory?